# What is the OSX keyboard shortcut to zoom in, in the Firefox Developer console?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When my cursor is in the developer console, and I try to hit `Cmd-+` meaning, `Cmd-shift-=`, the zoom-in happens in the main window, rather than in the Developer Console or whatever they call what opens up when you hit `Cmd-option-i`

I can *zoom out* fine, and `Cmd-0` restores the zoom level to 100%. But I can't zoom *in*.

How can I do that? I have an MBP 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts the shortcuts on macOS to zoom in and out are <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

Note that you have to focus the DevTools (e.g. by clicking into them) to make the zoom work within them.

As mentioned in [a related answer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Framework), this might also be related to your keyboard layout.

Comment: I do have my focus in the DevTools frame. I captured this in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX-V62K2wGA - you can see I start with the focus in DevTools and hit `Ctrl +` but the window above (containing this comment zooms in.) `Ctrl -` causes the DevTools frame to zoom out, as does `Ctrl-0`

Comment: Then it might be an issue related your keyboard layout. I have Windows with a German keyboard layout and it works for me. I don't think it's a general issue on macOS, otherwise more people would complain. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42707670/432681 gives a deeper explanation You may also [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Framework) for this, so the Mozilla people can fix it.