# Restore font size on Firefox developer tool

Tags: firefox, font-size, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox only lets me shrink the font size of the Developer Tools via <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. I can't enlarge the font by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>. (Pressing these keys will only change the font size of the web page, even right after I click and focus on the Developer Tools.)

I was able to restored to the default font size via `about:config` > `devtools.toolbox.zoomValue` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046452/1271621). However, it would be onerous to reopen the configs page every time I accidentally shrink the font size of the Developer Tools.

How do I make the Developer Tools tab responsive to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for font enlargement?

---

**System Info**

OS: macOS 14.1.1

Firefox: 120.0.1

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Firefox DevTools documentation for keyboard shortcuts](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/keyboard_shortcuts/index.html#toolbox), <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> *should* increase the font size. So, if it doesn't, it is a bug.

Resetting the font size should work via <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>.